# How do I add items to all windows' window menus?

Tags: windows, winapi

I'd like to write a utility in the vein of [PowerMenu](http://www.abstractpath.com/powermenu/) - it adds some extra stuff into all applications' window menus (alt-space, that menu).

How does one go about doing this?

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138616/how-to-add-custom-item-to-system-menu-in-c

Comment: Just please try to avoid putting your menu items at the bottom. There's nothing I hate more than apps like HTML Help that puts an "About" menu where I instinctively expect Close to be.

Comment: Don't worry, that drives me crazy too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Inject some code to each window's process.
2. Use [GetSystemMenu()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647985(VS.85).aspx) in the hook to retrieve that windows "alt-space" menu
3. Make your modifications
4. Cleanup

I'd personally use [SetWindowsHookEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx), WH_CALLWNDPROC, and a [CallWndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644975(VS.85).aspx) to achieve step 1, requiring a call to [UnhookWindowsHookEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644993(VS.85).aspx) in step 4, and bit of custom message pumping to get step 2 rolling.  That's just personal preference though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in such a way:

1. Get all the windows that have a system menu
2. Insert custom items into the menu
3. Install hooks that will send events from menu items to your process
4. Handle events inside your process

You can find an example here https://github.com/AlexanderPro/SmartSystemMenu

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Note that if that's your project you're linking to, you should [mention that fact in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)