# Modifying global system menus

Tags: c#, hook, menu

Is there a way in C# to globally add a menu item to all the system menus on all active windows? Perhaps under the "Maximize" command?

Comment: If your design requires you to do this, you need to re-think your design.

Comment: I am trying to write a program that will allow me to "pin" any window so that it is always on top of all the other windows.

Comment: What if the user has another application that uses the same technique you end up using to put a window on top, who wins?

Comment: Well then I would assume both windows would be on top. One could be moved to the upper left hand corner of the screen and the second could be moved to the lower right hand corner of the screen, both staying on top of all other windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can't be done in managed code.  And it would be remarkably difficult even in unmanged code.   Basically you would have to inject your code into every process, and then insert items into the local system menus, and then hook the main window proc to intercept the WM_SYSCOMMAND messages so that you could make the menu items do something.

You CAN write code that will add the WS_TOPMOST style to (most) windows (security permitting) just by using `FindWindow` to get the window handle and then `SetWindowLong` to change the window style.

But you won't be able to put the UI for this into other process's system menus.

Comment: Thanks for the reply John. So the best way to go at this is to write something like Spy++ that lets you "select" a window, then use SetWindowLong on that window to change the window style?

Comment: An elegant way to do this without code injection is described at http://stackoverflow.com/q/138616/103167

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by writing all the logic in C# in an exe file. You will also have to write some code in C/C++ as a hook, which will send events from the menu items to your exe file. You can find an example here https://github.com/AlexanderPro/SmartSystemMenu

Comment: If you are linking to your own project then you need to disclose that in the answer.