# C# Draw Custom Button on Existing Window's TitleBar

Tags: c#, button, window, titlebar

I need to figure out how to draw a custom button next to the minimize, maximize and close buttons within the Titlebar for ALL open windows.  I have seen some solutions for how this might be done for a user created form, but none for existing windows.

The end product will be a button next to the minimize button (on every window) that will allow that window to be moved and resized to a second monitor.

Comment: Just curious why you wouldn't just use UltraMon for this type of functionality rather than writing it on your own.  It's cheap, and it works well.

Comment: http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about it.  This is monstrously difficult, and you still wouldn't get it to work on all Windows because of security concerns - The only way to do this involves injecting code into every other process.

see this thread for a slightly longer explanation.

[Modifying global system menus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943965/modifying-global-system-menus/1944021#1944021)