# Is it possible to change Windows XP "Jumplist"

Tags: windows-xp, contextmenu, jump-list

I want to change the context menu of any application that is attached to the taskbar (should be the same as clicking a folder icon left, e.g. [this](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v34/TulsaRose/Help%20Tips/Max-1.jpg))

Is there any way to do this for Windows XP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you need system wide hook that handles WM_SYSCOMMAND message to modify system menu. See similar question in c#. 
 [Modifying global system menus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943965/modifying-global-system-menus)